# Volumes of solids of revolution

Tags: calculus, rotations, volume

This might be a somewhat unorthodox question. I am wondering if there are any simple guidelines or tips/tricks to better understand volumes of solids of revolution.

E.g. the simple assignment and my own thoughts. Please correct me!

> $\text{Let a and h be positive, let A be the area in the first quadrant bounded by }$$ax^2$$ \text{the y-axis and y=h.}$
>
> The area $A$ is rotated about the $y$-axis. Find the volume of the solid created.

My initial thoughts would be to graph a rough sketch of the scenario. So I have a shape bounded by $ax^2$ on the right, by $x=0$ on the left, and $y=h$ at the top. The lower bound is not relevant, as it is 0 before it crosses the axis.

So, if I set $y=h \land y=ax^2$ to be equal, I can find the $x$-value where I need to integrate *to*, i.e. $ax^2=h \implies x=\sqrt{\dfrac{h}{a}}$.

My guess would be: $$\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{\tfrac{h}{a}}}(ax^2)^2 - (h)^2 dx \implies$$

$$\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{\tfrac{h}{a}}}(a^2x^4) - \dfrac{a^2h^2}{a^2}\,dx=\pi a^2\int_0^{\sqrt{\tfrac{h}{a}}}x^4-\dfrac{h^2}{a^2}\,dx = \pi a^2 \left( \int_0^{\sqrt{\tfrac{h}{a}}}x^4\,dx - \dfrac{h^2}{a^2}{\sqrt{\dfrac{h}{a}}}\right)$$

$$\pi a^2 \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{\tfrac{h}{a}}^5}{5} - \dfrac{h^2}{a^2}{\sqrt{\dfrac{h}{a}}}\right) = \dots$$

So, at this point I am both algebraically stuck and somewhat close to giving up. Any advice?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to offer a closure to this question, this may benefit from the inclusion of diagrams.  **Erlend** appears to be proposing the use of "disks", but it should be keep in mind that disk "slices" are always *perpendicular* to the rotation axis.  Since that is "vertical" in this problem, the slices are "horizontal" and so will have "thicknesses" $ \ dy \ . $  So we will need to integrate in the $ \ y-$ direction, which requires expressing the disk radii as a function of $ \ y \ . $

[image]

The function inversion for the parabola is $ \ x = \sqrt{\frac{y}{a}} \ $ , and this is applicable over the entire interval in the $ \ y-$ direction, $ \ 0 \le y \le  h \ , $ so the volume integral is

$$ \int_0^h \ \pi \ [x(y)]^2 \ \ dy \ = \ \pi \ \int_0^h \ \frac{y}{a} \ \ dy \ = \ \frac{\pi}{ a} \ \left( \ \frac{y^2}{2}   \vert_0^h \ \right) \ = \ \frac{\pi \ h^2}{2 \ a} \ , $$

as already shown by **Jean-Claude Arbaut**.

[The apparent discrepancy in "dimensionality" is due to the fact that $ \ a \ $ has the "dimension" of *inverse* length.  Our result is correctly a three-dimensional volume.]

Some of **Erlend**'s confusion may be arising from the requirements for applying the "shell method."  For that, the shell-wall "slices" are always *parallel* to the rotation axis.

[image]

The shell "thicknesses" are now $ \ dx \ , $ so the integration is carried out in the $ \ x-$ direction, which will use the single interval $ \ 0 \le x \le \sqrt{\frac{h}{a}} \ , $ as he was writing (but for the wrong method).  It is the *integrand* which must be "split", as the "height" of the shells extends from the parabola "upward" to the "horizontal" line $ \ y = h \ . $ Here, we express the function for the parabola in terms of $ \ x \ , $ making the shell heights $ \ h - ax^2 \ . $

The radii of the shells again extend perpendicularly from the rotation axis, so these are given by $ \ r = x \ . $  The shell volume integration is thus

$$ \int \ 2 \pi \ r \ h \ \ dr \ \ \rightarrow \ \ 2 \pi \ \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{h}{a}}} \ x \ \cdot \ (h - ax^2) \ \ dx $$

$$ = \ 2 \pi \ \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{h}{a}}} \ hx - ax^3 \ \ dx \ = \ 2\pi \ \left( \ \frac{hx^2}{2}  \ - \ \frac{ay^4}{4}  \ \vert_0^{\sqrt{h/a}} \ \right)  $$

$$ = \ 2 \pi \ \left( \ \frac{h}{2} \cdot \frac{h}{a}  \ - \ \frac{a}{4} \cdot  \frac{h^2}{a^2} \   \right) \ = \ 2 \pi \ \cdot \ \frac{h^2}{4a}  \ = \ \frac{\pi \ h^2}{2 \ a} \ , $$

as found above.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if a volume is defined by "stacked" plane surfaces of area $A(y)$ for $y$ from $0$ to $H$, then the volume is given by

$$V=\int_0^H A(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$$

Here, your plane surfaces are discs, whose radii are defined by the $y=ax^2$ curve.

That is, $R(y) = x=\sqrt{y/a}$, so the area is $A(y)=\pi R(y)^2=\pi y/a$, and

$$V=\int_0^{h} \pi \frac y a \mathrm{d}y$$

Can you conclude now?

Comment: I can, sure. I do wonder how you **see** that solution though..?

Comment: Imagine you draw your volume, and you "slice" it. Actually, I was looking for such a slicing, because I know this formula and it's one of the easiest to compute volumes. You have also [Guldin theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem), but they would be uneasy here (you have to compute the position of the centroid of your piece of parabola). Another way is writing the volume "directly" as a double integral, but again it's not as simple.

Comment: So my approach isn't wrong, just a heck of a lot more complex than necessary? Bah! I still don't quite grasp this whole area of rotating shapes about axis'.

Comment: Your idea isn't wrong, but I'm not sure I follow your computation ;-)

Comment: oh my, is it wrong? I was thinking splitting the integrals was a good idea.

Comment: @Erlend Actually, it's the $(ax^2)^2-(h)^2$, that I don't understand.